# UTF-16 support in GWT/GXT application

Tags: gwt, gxt, utf-16

I have an GWT/GXT application running on UTF-8 encoding.We would like it to support UTF-16.That is, we would like the UTF-16 encoded characters copy-pasted from word/other sources to be safely propagated to the DB and the UTF-16 encoded characters in Oracle DB to be displayed seamlessly in the UI .

Is it possible to implement this in GWT/GXT ? If so, how do we go about implementing this ?Please help.

Comment: Do you have any example where you are not able to get UTF-16 encoded characters properly displayed or stored? If yes, please include it with a bit of related code so people can help you better

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but Yes -The character ȩ is not displayed properly in the UI using GXT neither is the character ǅ . I am not sure if UTF-16 is the answer but I need a solution to support these characters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to saving the source code encoding toUTF-8 . I changed this in maven and selected the appropriate font . Now everything seems to be fine .